# How to prove that $ \Bigg(\sum^{n}\limits_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}}\Bigg)^{2} \le n\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ for $n\ge1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

> I need to prove Prove the inequality
>   $$ \Bigg(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}}\Bigg)^{2} \le n\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}, $$
>   where $n$ is a positive integer.

Equivalently 
$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}} \le \sqrt[4]{\frac{n^3}{n+1}}, $$

Then proceed by induction assuming it is true for $n-1$ we have

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}}  \le \sqrt[4]{\frac{(n-1)^3}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n-\sqrt{n^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}}  $$

Then one need to show that the last term is not greater than $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{n^3}{n+1}}$$ which is not an obvious task.

> **Question;** Is there an alternative way of proving this without appealing induction or can anyone help to prove this last step?

Comment: You could improve the question by adding additional context. What is the source of the inequality? Why do you need to prove it? What interest does it have?  As it stands, the post has little motivation.

Comment: @CarlMummert  I get your point but this a rude exercise given like that and no further comment were given and patently the answer below is correct and motivating since you can see it as application Cauchy schwarz inequality along with Telescoping summation

Comment: No idea why a down vote here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a combination of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and a telescope sum.

According to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\Bigg(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}}\Bigg)^{2} \le \left( \sum_{k=1}^n 1^2 \right)\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} \right) = n \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} \right)$$

The sum on the right-hand side can now be transformed into a telescoping sum:

$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k-\sqrt{k^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} \right) =  \left(  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{(k-1)(k+1)}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} \right)\\ =  \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}} - \frac{\sqrt{k-1}}{\sqrt{k}} \right) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

Done.

Comment: great job so cool